# ¿Cómo permitir mayúsculas y minúsculas en una celda con lista de validación?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una hoja excel, donde hay una columna cuyas celdas tienen una lista desplegable, y para ello he usado una lista de validación de la opción validación de datos para celdas, con las opciones A, B y M. (en mayúsculas)

Por tanto en esas celdas sólo se aceptan una de esas 3 opciones. 
Para elegir una opción, se puede elegir de la lista directamente que se despliega en cada una de esas celdas, o escribiendo directamente la letra que se quiera de entre esas 3.

Pues bien, ¿hay alguna forma de que se acepten también esas letras en minúsculas cuando el usuario escribe una de ellas en la celda, pero sin tener que añadir las opciones (las letras en minúscula) en la lista desplegable?, ¿o en caso de tener que añadirlas en la opción de validación, hay forma de que no se muestren en la lista desplegable de cada celda?

He probado mediante la fórmula MAYSUC() pero al tener validación de datos no lo acepta. No se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sé que es una consulta antigua pero por si alguien lo está buscando, como era mi caso, pongo aquí la solución que he encontrado. Si en lugar de indicar los valores de la lista directamente en la validación de datos, los cogemos de un rango, permite entrar mayúsculas y minúsculas sin dar error. Luego se podría hacer el cambio desde VBA como indicaba lois6b.

Comment: Hola, nuevamente te invitamos a revisar [ask] que te brinda información de como realizar preguntas en el sitio, estas sean bien recibidas y además obtengas la ayuda requerida, te sugerimos modificar el formato de tu pregunta agrega lo que investigaste o trataste, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un evento onChange para la celda H5

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("H5")) Is Nothing Then Macro
End Sub
```

En la funcion Macro (o como tu la llames) puedes comprobar que sea uno de los valores correctos o si está en minúscula o no, poner mayuscula igualmente con `UCase(string)`.

---

He encontrado tambien ésto: Es un evento on change que cambia a mayusculas el texto. Puedes cambiar el rango para que afecte a las celdas que quieras, o filas completas. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Cambia a Mayusculas
        Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. El problema es que al estar la validación de datos en la opción del menu de validaciones para poder crear la lista desplegable,  primero por lo que veo valida el dato y luego hace la función Intersect. Por tanto antes de convertir a mayúsculas me valida el dato (ejemplo una "a") y al ver que está en minúsculas y no coincide con ninguna opción salta error.

Comment: pues no pongas la validacion por el menu y hazla programaticamente

Comment: si, pero para ello me tocaría insertar controles de formulario o activeX y tengo mas de 500mil filas. No puedo modificarlas y meter un control para cada fila. Lo

Comment: hago un edit a mi respuesta

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar con la validación de datos. Salta el error primero antes de convertir a mayúsculas. Al final tendré que quitarla aunque en principio no se me permite quitarla. Seguiré investigando. Gracias @lois6b

Comment: es todo lo que se me ocurre/encuentro. Suerte, a ver si alguien contesta algo distinto ;)